# How do you use the accelstepper arduino library to move a specified number of steps, check an external input, then continue?

Tags: c, arduino, stepper

I'm trying to use the Accelstepper library to run my stepper motor. My objective is to run the motor for a specific number of steps, check to see if an external switch is pressed, and then continue at a constant speed. However, I have found that I cannot specify a number of steps and then run at a constant speed afterwards.

My current code runs a while loop and runs for the number of steps that I specify while ignoring any code regarding my switch.

```
motor.setCurrentPosition(0);
while(motor.currentPosition()!=50){
  motor.setSpeed(500);
  motor.runSpeed();
}
delay(1000);
if (digitalRead(switchPin)==LOW){
  motor.setSpeed(500);
  motor.runSpeed();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the last `motor.runSpeed()` in an infinite loop. Now it gets executed only once if `switchpin` is low.
After that, the program exits the if condition and terminates.

```
motor.setSpeed(500);
motor.setCurrentPosition(0);

while(motor.currentPosition()!=50){
    motor.runSpeed();
}

delay(1000);

if (digitalRead(switchPin)==LOW){

    while (1) {
        motor.runSpeed();
    }

}
```

In the while loop you can check another vlag to break out of it, if needed.